# Diferencia de años, entre dos fechas

Tags: java, poo

Tengo un dudas sobre la clase Date, bueno en realidad no se como hacer la resta entre dos fechas y que me retorne el numero de años en este caso.

Tengo la fecha en formato Date, pero no puedo hacer la resta, es diferencia entre la fecha actual y la fecha que yo ingrese. Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento.

**Clase Principal**

```
//Clase Principal
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Principal{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws ParseException{
        Scanner teclado =new Scanner(System.in);
        Date fech;
        //Captura de fecha
        System.out.println("Ingrese fecha de ingreso a la empresa dd-mm-yyyy");
        String fechaIngre;
        fechaIngre=teclado.nextLine();
        //Creacion de objeto
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        //Transformar a date
        fech=sdf.parse(fechaIngre);
        //Objeto Funcionario
        Funcionarios fun1 =new Funcionarios("Rodrigo",524.254);
        fun1.setAñosServicio(fech);//Se ingresa al funcionario la fecha de ingreso //Metodo
        System.out.print("Nombre del empleado: ");
        System.out.println(fun1.getNombre());
        System.out.print("Salario: ");
        System.out.println(fun1.getSalario());
        System.out.print("Fecha de ingreso a la empresa: ");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(fun1.getFecha()));
    }
}
```

**Clase Funcionario**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
public class Funcionarios{
    //Atributos
    private String nombre;
    private double salario;
    private Date fechaIngreso;

    //Constructor
    public  Funcionarios(String nom, double sala){
            this.nombre=nom;
            this.salario=sala;
        }

    //Metodo
    //Devuelve el nombre
    public String getNombre(){
        return(this.nombre);
        }
    //Devuelve el salario
    public double getSalario(){
            return(this.salario);
        }

    //Ingresa fecha de ingreso
    public void setAñosServicio(Date años){
            this.fechaIngreso=años;
        }

        //Devuelve la fecha tipo DATE
    public Date getFecha(){
            return(this.fechaIngreso);
        }
        //determinar la cantidad de años en la empresa
    public int tiemEmpresa(){
        int annos;
        annos=parseInt(this.);
    }
}
```

He buscado también en la documentación de la clase, y no logro entender como realizar esta resta, también nos pidieron que la fecha la ingresáramos en `String`.

Comment: Que JDK esta usando, si es 8 puede usar LocalDate

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una solución usando [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) en Java 7:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date fechaInicial = new GregorianCalendar(2010, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11).getTime();
        Date fechaFinal= new GregorianCalendar(2015, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 25).getTime();
        System.out.println("Número de años entre las fechas: " + obtenerAnios(fechaInicial,fechaFinal));
    }

    public static int obtenerAnios(Date first, Date last) {
        Calendar a = getCalendar(first);
        Calendar b = getCalendar(last);
        int diff = b.get(Calendar.YEAR) - a.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) > b.get(Calendar.MONTH) ||
            (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) == b.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&   
            a.get(Calendar.DATE) > b.get(Calendar.DATE))) {
            diff--;
        }
        return diff;
    }

    public static Calendar getCalendar(Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        cal.setTime(date);
        return cal;
    }
}
```

En este caso te regresaría lo siguiente:

```
Número de años entre las fechas: 5
```

La respuesta la tomé de ésta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215152/3191739)